# property issues python 3.8.1 visual studio code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I'm currently running python 3.8.1 on visual studio code.

Consider the class below:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, price):
        self.set_price(price)

    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price

    def set_price(self, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Price cannot be negative.")
        self.__price = value

    price = property(get_price, set_price)


product = Product(10)
product.price = -1
print(product.price)
```

Theoretically, it should raise the error, as it would do without the property feature. However, for some reason, the property function does not reference the methods get_price or set_price. Thus, the output from this code is -1 rather than the ValueError being raised. Is there any package or installations additional to ms-python.python class or code runner than need to be enabled for this to happen. it doesn't make any sense because the tutorial I'm watching runs python 3.7.0.

[image: Please find below the screenshot of my code to visualise the issue:]

Comment: When I run that code, I get the the ValueError.

Comment: It looks like you're actually running it with Python2 (I can reproduce). This is because you're probably not in a venv, and you're calling `python`.

Comment: do you know how to convert my visual studio 8 to python

Comment: Just run python3 instead of python